# parsing error while parsing document using ow3c.dom.Document object, (Unicode: 0x1a) was found in the element content of the document

Tags: java, xml

I am getting error : `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 14515; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1a) was found in the element content of the document`.

my xml file content in which I getting error:

```
 <Product>
          <Description>672577000 3M 4540 DISPOSABLE COVERALL → XL</Description>
 </Product>
```

I got this error while I am parsing document using org.w3c.dom.Document object, error is occurred due to → in input file. so how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Yes I am starting line with <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>, but also getting this error

Comment: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1a) means that there is an invalid character. check to make sure no double byte char or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I resolved this by using below code
String removedUnicodeChar  = "DISPOSABLE COVERALL → XXL</Description></Order> ↔ ↕ ↑ ↓ → ABC";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Cntrl}|\\uFFFD]");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(removedUnicodeChar);
if(m.find()){
    System.out.println("Control Characters found");
    removedUnicodeChar = m.replaceAll("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No all characters are allowed in a xml files. Here is a link for you to find which one is allowed or is discouraged and the reset is not allowed:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML

Yours (→) is not allowed.

Comment: So how can I remove this type of character programmatically from  file ?

Comment: you should consider whats the significance of this character first? is it something you came up with? then it is easy just come up with something that xml accepts. is it something out of your control (maybe something that is generated by another system) ? Then it is not as easy. anyways there should find a character or set of characters that is out of domain of data. This could be a candid replacement for your evil character (→).

Comment: As to how you remove it? It is just a simple preprocessioning on the file to remove or replace all instances of the character. You might look at a simple tutorial on how to do that.